# JavaScript treeviews with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've been using knockout.js fairly effectively in my latest web-app, and it's great. However, I now need to implement a treeview, and the current contenders are here: http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php

JSTree is the one under current development, but seems to require to be initialised with html or json - under knockout, I ideally would like to have the ul list built automatically, and the treeview then automatically update after that. The "Treeview" one seems to be able to use an existing ul list, but has been deprecated

Has anyone else had any experience of using a treeview with knockout?

Answer (score 6):

turns out this one does: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

so far, anyway.

hope this is of use to someone else

Comment: How did that end up working with Knockout.js?

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you did this?

Comment: The bassistance plugin is not being maintained as of April 2010, and their page says a successor will be part of jQuery UI: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree.  However, that jQueryUI wiki page is over a year old.  Looks like http://jsTree.com is currently the best free choice, haven't tried any pay versions like http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

TreeView won't work with KnockoutJS, as both modify DOM model - you won't be able to access your observables from JSTree.
Google for Knockout Kendo, it's a mashup of Knockout and Kendo, which will allow you to use TreeView in your Knockout based website.

EDIT:
However, note that Kendo is under GNU-GPL license, which means, IIRC, that you would have to publish your website as open-source.